# What's the latest possible version of IE11 in windows 7,8 and 8.1

Tags: windows, browser, internet-explorer, javascript, .net-framework

I'm having difficulties with finding information about minor versions of IE11.

I'm maintaining a legacy web application but due to the usage of multiple (inlcuding some outdated) components and plugins there are browsers in which the application does not work properly. It is not possible to refactor it with newer components, so I am bound to work with what already has been made.

I have pinpointed the browsers in which it does not work as it should, and it appears to give the most problems with specific subversions of IE11.0.9600 on systems with either windows 7, 8 or 8.1. As a quick fix I want to show a message that the user should update his/her browser whenever one of the "faulty" browsers is detected. But before I can make that happen, I need to be sure users actually CAN update their browser to a newer version. And that rises other questions.

A colleague of mine uses IE11 on a Windows 10 system, and his version is 11.309.16299.0. I'm using IE11 on a windows 8.1 system and my version is 11.0.9600.18618. My colleagues has a higher version the mine, so I figured it's possible to update my version but I have the auto-update checkbox checked so another question is why it's still so behind...

So basically my questions are:

- What's the highest possible version of IE11 on windows 7, 8 and 8.1?
- Why is my version (on win 8.1) way behind compared to my colleague (on win 10)?
- Is it possible to update any further?
- How? (Microsofts support and documentation on Internet Explorer is pretty... Bad)
- Or am I doomed to tell the users to use another browser like Chrome or Firefox?

Thanks in advance for everyone who can help me at least a little bit further!

Cheers!

Rik

Comment: Its better to ask One question not 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the highest possible version of IE11 on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1?

The highest version of Internet Explorer that runs on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 is Internet Explorer 11.  As for which build specifically that is since that continuously is changing, the answer to that question would be, the current build included in the monthly cumulative update for that specific version of Windows.

> Why is my version (on win 8.1) way behind compared to my colleague (on
>   win 10)?

While you have a different build, you are still running IE11, and provided you have all cumulative updates installed you are running the current build of IE11 for that version of Windows.

> Is it possible to update any further?

The build of IE11 is based on which version of Windows you are using.  So `11.309.16299.0` cannot run on any version of Windows other than the current build of Windows 10 (1803). Likewise, `11.0.9600.18618` is the current version of IE11 (I presume you have all security patched installed) on Windows 8.1.

> How? (Microsofts support and documentation on Internet Explorer is
>   pretty... Bad)

What you want is not possible.  You should install all cumulative updates, for the targeted version of Windows, so you are running the current build of IE11.

> Or am I doomed to tell the users to use another browser like Chrome or
>   Firefox?

As indicated before, if you install all cumulative updates as they are released for the targeted version of Windows 10, then you are already running the current build of IE11.

Which means using another browser like Chrome or Firefox is a decision, that has no bearing on the fact, different builds of IE11 run on different versions of Windows.

> As a quick fix I want to show a message that the user should update
>   his/her browser whenever one of the "faulty" browsers is detected. But
>   before I can make that happen, I need to be sure users actually CAN
>   update their browser to a newer version. And that raises other
>   questions.

Please do not break the internet by trying to detect a specific build of IE11.  Verifying they are using IE11, will verify they are running a compatible browser, attempting to detect the build of IE11 will be a nightmare for your users.

> I have pinpointed the browsers in which it does not work as it should,
>   and it appears to give the most problems with specific subversions of
>   IE11.0.9600 on systems with either Windows 7, 8 or 8.1.

As for a possible reason, this is the case, Windows 8 and above have a significantly better touch-screen support compared to that of Windows 7.  So part of the reason Windows 8+ are running a different build of IE11, when compared to Windows 7, is that there are targeted touch screen features those builds do support.

I would like to point out the problems your website has with IE11, likely has to do with the legacy components, and nothing to do with the build of IE11 being used.  The incompatibility might be with the IE11 plugins themselves, there are significant differences, between the security features of Windows 7 and Windows 8+

Comment: Thank you very much for this insightful answer! I was affraid that the legacy components are the source of my problems, yet I cannot change this in the near future... Oh well, at least I've learned something :)